# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file - .net core & Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack

I keep getting the following error web running a production build of a .net core angular 4 application. Those are 2 node packages I installed and looks like their is some issue with webpack reading those files only for production builds. Any thoughts?

```
ERROR in ./$$_gendir/~/ngx-mydatepicker/dist/ngx-my-date-picker.component.ngfactory.ts
  Module parse failed: d:\a\1\s\Vacant2\$$_gendir\node_modules\ngx-mydatepicker\dist\ngx-my-date-picker.component.ngfactory.ts Unexpected token (14:28)
  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
  | import * as i3 from 'ngx-mydatepicker/dist/directives/ngx-my-date-picker.focus.directive';
  | import * as i4 from 'ngx-mydatepicker/dist/services/ngx-my-date-picker.util.service';
  | const styles_NgxMyDatePicker:any[] = ['.ngxmdp .headertodaybtn,.ngxmdp .monthcell,.ngxmdp .weekdaytitle{overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap}.ngxmdp *{-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;padding:0;margin:0}.ngxmdp .selector{position:absolute;padding:0;border:1px solid #CCC;border-radius:4px;z-index:100000;animation:selectorfadein 60ms}.ngxmdp .selector:focus{border:1px solid #ADD8E6;outline:0}@keyframes selectorfadein{from{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}}.ngxmdp .selectorarrow{background:#FAFAFA;padding:0}.ngxmdp .selectorarrow:after,.ngxmdp .selectorarrow:before{bottom:100%;border:solid transparent;content:" ";height:0;width:0;position:absolute}.ngxmdp .selectorarrow:after{border-color:rgba(250,250,250,0);border-bottom-color:#FAFAFA;border-width:10px;margin-left:-10px}.ngxmdp .selectorarrow:before{border-color:rgba(204,204,204,0);border-bottom-color:#CCC;border-width:11px;margin-left:-11px}.ngxmdp .selectorarrow:focus:before{bord...
  | export const RenderType_NgxMyDatePicker:i0.RendererType2 = i0.ɵcrt({encapsulation:2,
  |     styles:styles_NgxMyDatePicker,data:{}});
   @ ./$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.server.ngfactory.ts 10:0-115
   @ ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts

  ERROR in ./$$_gendir/~/ngx-loading/ngx-loading.ngfactory.ts
  Module parse failed: d:\a\1\s\Vacant2\$$_gendir\node_modules\ngx-loading\ngx-loading.ngfactory.ts Unexpected token (12:35)
  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
  | import * as i1 from 'ngx-loading';
  | import * as i2 from '@angular/common';
  | export const LoadingModuleNgFactory:i0.NgModuleFactory<i1.LoadingModule> = i0.ɵcmf(i1.LoadingModule,
  |     ([] as any[]),(_l:any) => {
  |       return i0.ɵmod([i0.ɵmpd(512,i0.ComponentFactoryResolver,i0.ɵCodegenComponentFactoryResolver,
   @ ./$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/components/app/app.component.ngfactory.ts 9:0-94
   @ ./$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.server.ngfactory.ts
   @ ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts
```

Comment: Are you running `aot` build by chance? I had a similar issue with `aot`.

Comment: yes! Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I tried several things like `npm install` and replacing `*` of `import * from ` with directive name, but didn't fix the problem completely. It did solve some of them. I ended up not using the `aot` at the end. This happened after I updated the NPM version as I were able to build `aot` before.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but there are some stuff maybe relevant to yours. https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/426

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1168#issuecomment-320026397

Just needed to remove include: /ClientApp/ from myh webpack.config.js.